# how to give dynamic name for checkbox in php

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how to give dynamic names to checkboxes with counters.I know that it is possible by javascript.But I would like to do in php.Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: Just echo the counter value with the name when echoing out the checkbox

Comment: Please, share your desire html output here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="foo[' . $i . ']" /> <br />';
}
```

Is this what you want?

This example will return an array of values from the checkboxes. Modify the example to your needs.